# Segmentation Fault whenever i try to cast unsigned char* to a X509*

Tags: c, openssl, x509

I'm trying to send a certificate over an ssl socket to a client. The certificate is stored in a database as a blob.

Whenever i try to cast the unsigned char* pointer that receives the data to a X509* and access the X509, my client segfaults even tho the server does the same but it works just fine. I printed the data passed in hex and they match so im not sure what the issue.

Server:

```
//returns the blob containing the cert from db.
unsigned char *cert = get_cert(name);
X509* certt = (X509 *) cert;
//gets size of certificate to send over socket
int cert_size = i2d_X509(certt, NULL);

//prints cert common name and binary data as hex
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
unsigned char *user = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(certt), 0, 0);
printf("%s\n", user);
for (int i = 0; i < cert_size; i++){
    printf("%X", cert[i]);
}

//sends cert size then the cert.
char message[64];
snprintf(message, 64, "/cert %d", cert_size);
ssl_block_write(ssl, serverfd, message, strlen(message));
ssl_block_write(ssl, serverfd, cert, cert_size);
```

Client:

```
//allocates enough memory to receive cert
unsigned char *data = malloc(size);
printf("%d\n", ssl_block_read(ssl, serverfd, data, size));

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    printf("%X", data[i]);

X509 *cert = (X509 *) data;
unsigned char *user = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), 0, 0);
printf("%s\n", user);
```

Comment: I feel you have not provided enough information, for instance we want to know the hex data you are printing and `X509` structure definition(Which I'm not able to find online).

Comment: Just an observation: in the server you are not accessing the data using the type-casted ```certt```

Comment: how do you no the program crashes because of the casting? It actually sounds unreasonable as there is no pointer de-referencing by the the cast itself.

Comment: `i2d_X509(certt, NULL);` likely de-references the data, so that's potentially a strict aliasing violation. Though I suspect the bug is rather related to alignment/padding. Impossible to say with the little information given.

Comment: Maybe is `get_cert` allowed to return NULL?

Comment: You cannot do this! The X509 structure is not directly serializable in this way. It contains pointers etc which will not serialize correctly like this. If you need to store it as a blob then you should convert it to DER first using i2d_x509(), and then when you read it back in again you need to use d2i_x509() to convert it back again. I have no idea why it works for you on the server. It should not.

Comment: Hi @MattCaswell, I don't find in which include is defined the structure x509_st (`typedef struct x509_st X509;` is in ossl_typ,h).Do you know anything about where the structure definition is declared?

Comment: Assuming you are using OpenSSL 1.0.0 or later then the type is opaque. The definition is only held in OpenSSL internal header files which are not available to application authors. It's definition (including its size) could actually change from one OpenSSL patch release to the next. If you just want to look for curiosity, it is here: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/cdb2763e7daeea87c61ea874ae820046d84dd016/include/crypto/x509.h#L158-L186

Comment: @MattCaswell this should be an answer

Comment: I made my comment into an answer as suggested by @n.'pronouns'm.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this! The X509 structure is not directly serializable in this way. It contains pointers etc which will not serialize correctly like this. If you need to store it as a blob then you should convert it to DER first using i2d_X509(), and then when you read it back in again you need to use d2i_X509() to convert it back again. I have no idea why it works for you on the server. It should not.